# Amount of unknown parameters in compressible Euler equations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, ideal-gas, degrees-of-freedom

I'm looking at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29#Compressible_Euler_equations) for the compressible Euler equations.

To me it seems, in the 1-dimensional case, there should be 3 unknowns: density, velocity, and pressure. This is because the energy $E$ is a function of density and velocity, as the internal energy $e$ seems like it should be constant, because the flow is adiabatic. Additionally, it is stated

> The equations above thus represent conservation of mass, momentum, and energy. Mass density, Flow velocity and pressure are the so-called physical variables, while mass density, momentum density and total energy density are the so-called conserved variables.

So three unknowns, right?

However, [later in the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29#Constraints), it is stated that

> there are thus N+2 equations and N+3 unknowns

So there should be 3 equations and 4 unknowns. Thus an equation of state, relating pressure, energy, density, and velocity, is invoked, allowing us to solve for 4 unknowns with 4 equations.

However, before it appeared to me that there were only 3 unknowns. Is it that the internal energy $e$ is nonconstant, which gives us the fourth unknown, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The equations above thus represent conservation of mass, momentum, and energy. Mass density, Flow velocity and pressure are the so-called physical variables, while mass density, momentum density and total energy density are the so-called conserved variables.
>
> So three unknowns, right?

Actually, there are four variables: density, velocity, pressure and total energy.  Density, pressure and energy are scalars (the +3) and velocity is a vector of dimension $N$.